# typeahead js detect element firing

Tags: typeahead.js

I use multiple typeahead fields with bootstrap 3 and can't find a way to detect which element triggered typeahead.

```
$('.mytypeaheads').typeahead({
  name: 'test',
  valueKey: 'myValue'
  remote : {
      url: 'typeahead.php?q=%QUERY',
      filter: function(parsedResponse) {

      }
  }
})
```

Need to know the element before sending the query to the server

Answer (score 0):

You could add a parameter to the query itself that identifies the specific field, and have the server return it. That way you'd have it in `parsedResponse`.

Comment: Thanks you are right, but I need to know the element before sending the query to the server not after. Edited original question and removed {{-- Detect which element fired typeahead --}} from the filter  to prevent confusion.